# How to add custom script in the product description?

Tags: javascript, css, magento, magento-1.9

I want to incorporate the code from this page (http://www.responderpse.com/fusion-49-single.php) into the long description field in the product listing. I've tried using and Iframe to just include the page but it's not adequate for the job (http://www.responderpse.com/feniex-fusion-led-lightbar-49.htm). I want the configuration tool to be part of the product description so it will post the result to the "Configuration" text field.

I guess the first question is can this be done? Then if so, how?

Comment: No - Magento will escape the HTML you insert to prevent you and your customers from CSRF and XSS attacks. You can achieve this but you'll need to add a custom block to your product page, define your own template and HTML for it.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I thought, but I was hoping there might be a simpler way. Makes sense tho. I appreciate the help.